# One piece of Javascript stopping another from loading

Tags: javascript, html

The below code, seems to cancel each other out, the top one works but the bottom one doesn't but when I remove the top part it all works fine!

A working example of both can be found here: http://www.healthygit.com as you can see the fade on the menu doesn't work but the accordion does... Does anyone know what's causing this?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#slidorion').slidorion({
        first: 2,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        effect: 'random'
    });
});
</script>

<title>Healthy Git | Health And Fitness Guide</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerimage"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
$('.megamenu').megaMenuCompleteSet({
    menu_speed_show : 300, // Time (in milliseconds) to show a drop down
    menu_speed_hide : 200, // Time (in milliseconds) to hide a drop down
    menu_speed_delay : 300, // Time (in milliseconds) before showing a drop   down
    menu_effect : 'hover_fade', // Drop down effect, choose between    'hover_fade', 'hover_slide', etc.
    menu_click_outside : 1, // Clicks outside the drop down close it (1 = true,    0 = false)
    menu_show_onload : 0 // Drop down to show on page load (type the number of      the drop down, 0 for none)
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript has errors in it.

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'megaMenuCompleteSet'

Either your menu is not loaded properly or not initialized, i guess.

You can debug javascript with Firebug(FF) or Inspect Element(Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything specifically wrong, but it's hard to see without the rest of the code. My guess is that the slidorion function has not been added to the jQuery prototype, ie:

```
$.fn.slidorion = function() {
    //do something
}
```